# If the hash of the multiplication is equal to the multiplication of the hash, how can this be used to leverage an attack?

Tags: hash

Assume a hash function $H:\left\{0,1\right\}^*\to G$ where $G$ is a group and assume that finding an inverse in $G$ is easy.

How can a preimage efficiently be found using the fact that $H(M_1\cdot M_2)=H(M_1)\cdot H(M_2)$ for $M_1,M_2\neq0$?

I've tried playing around with the group properties but I haven't gotten very far. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define multiplication in $\{0,1\}^*$?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Integer multiplication.

Comment: OK, and how do you map bitstrings to integers (and back)? Just by treating the bits as base-2 digits? If so, note that this map is not one-to-one, because it ignores leading zeros. Does your hash *also* ignore leading zeros? If so, that's a second-preimage attack right there. Of course, you seem to be asking for a first preimage, so it's not quite enough, but still...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm indeed asking for a first preimage

Comment: Technically, since $G$ is a group, all its elements must have inverses. In particular, $H(0)\in G$, so it has an inverse $H(0)^{-1}$. But since $0\cdot m=0$ for all $m$, it follows that $H(0)=H(0\cdot m)=H(0)\cdot H(m)$. Multiplying both sides by $H(0)^{-1}$ then yields $H(m)=1_G$, where $1_G$ is the identity element of $G$, for all $m$. Thus $H$ maps all inputs to $1_G$, and so finding preimages is either trivial (for $1_G$) or impossible (for any other elements of $G$). But I assume that's not the real answer; it seems more likely that your transcription of the exercise has a mistake.

Comment: Or perhaps you should in fact be using some other multiplicative structure for $\{0,1\}^*$; in particular, one that doesn't have a zero element. There *is* a fairly simple and commonly used bijective map from $\{0,1\}^*$ to the *positive* integers, obtained by first prepending a "1" to the bitstring and *then* reading the bits as base-2 digits. But that's not, IMO, *quite* so obvious that it should be assumed without being stated.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Indeed it does, I omitted the limitation that $H(M_1 \cdot M_2) = H(M_1) H(M_2)$ only holds for $M_1,M_2\neq 0$. I'll edit this into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a birthday attack:

Given $y\in G$ we want to find $w\in \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^*$ such that $H\left(w\right)=y$.

Randomly choose $x\in \left\{ 0,1 \right\}^*$ and calculate $H\left(x\right)$ and $yH\left(x\right)^{-1}$. Wait until we find $a,b$ such that $H(a)$=$yH\left(b\right)^{-1}$.

Now $w=ab$: $H(w)=H(ab)=H(a)H(b)=yH\left(b\right)^{-1}H(b)=y$.

Comment: do you think birthday complexity is the lowest complexity possible for this problem?